# $T^2 = T$ and $T$ is normal implies $T$ is hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:V\to V$ ($V$ is finite dimensional), a normal linear-operator such that $T^2=T$. Show that $T$ is hermitian.

So I know that if $T$ is normal then $T$ is hermitian iff the roots of $f_T(x)$ are real.

I also figured out that $T^2 = T$ implies $T(c)\in\mathbb{R}.\forall c\in\mathbb{C}$.

How can I deduce that indeed the roots are real?

Comment: Is $f_T(x)$ the characteristic polynomial? If so, you claim you only need to show the eigenvalues of $T$ are real, and you don't need the overkill result below, just the fact that the only eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$ will suffice. (If $T^2v = Tv = \lambda v$, then what can you say about $\lambda$?)

Comment: Thanks @Alex for this clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T^2=T$, then the only eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$ and/or $1$. If $T$ is normal, then it is unitarily diagonalizable. If $T$ is unitarily diagonalizable with real eigenvalues, then it is Hermitian.

This might be an overkill proof, but it gets the job done. Note that this requires $V$ to be finite dimensional.

Comment: It feels like an overkill - I am not familiar with the theorem "If T is unitarily diagonalizable with real eigenvalues, then it is Hermitian"

Comment: @Elimination That step is easy: since the eigenvector matrix $U$ is unitary, $T=U D U^*$, so $T^*=U^{**} D^* U^* = U D U^*=T$.

Comment: @Elimination The "hard" step is the second one.